# How to make \footnotemark color change?

Tags: hyperref, color, footnotes

MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true, 
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta
    }

\begin{document}

$\alpha$\footnote{$\alpha$: alpha} % Blue

\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\color{white}{$\mu$\footnotemark}} % White
\footnotetext{$\mu$: micro}

$\beta$\footnote{$\beta$: beta} % Blue

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

But what I'm trying to do is that the blue number 1 is white. And it should only be on this line. Other blue colors will remain blue.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still want the hyperlink, you can change the colour within a group:

```
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=white}\footnotemark}
```

If you don't want the link, then you can use the `NoHyper` environment:

```
\begin{NoHyper}\footnotemark\end{NoHyper}
```

Comment: It worked just the way I wanted.